# mov file not playing in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I have a video tag thats for playing a mov file, its working in Safari but not on chrome, what I need to set to make it playable in chrome too?

```
<video class="vp" width="480" height="320" controls="controls">
   <source src="One.mov" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="One.mov" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: I dont think `mov` video format is supported on html5...

Comment: check this wikipedia info about formats supported: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Harshith you're probably using a file type which the browser doesn't support.

Use a range of file types to ensure maximum compatibility, I see you are using 2 source tags in the example but only 1 file type.

I would recommend using Ogg & H.264 as these should cover the main browsers (excepting older versions) and then any additional file types as required depending on the browsers used by your audience.

Also, you may want to consider adding the old embed method for browsers which don't support HTML5 such as IE8 and lower. If you nest the 2 methods as below the browser will use the embed option only if it does not support HTML5.

```
<video>
  <source src="#" type="#" />
  <source src="#" type="#" />
  <source src="#" type="#" />
<object data="#">
  <embed src="#">
  </embed>
</object> 
</video>
```

Or you could just use YouTube...